Deep Understanding of Redirects and Canonical Tags and how Google processes them
I posted this question before in MOZ Forums, tbh i'm a bit disappointed, because nobody seemed to be able to answer my question. They just closed the topic after 1 useless answer.
I am new to StackExchange, but what i've seen so far, gives me hope, finally being in the right place. So with new hope of reaching any tech-affiliated crack, who can explain me this, i will post my question again here:
I'm just experimenting and would appreciate any insights into an issue I've encountered.
I had a webpage at "example.com/page". My .htaccess file included several SEO-related rules to remove ".html" extensions, handle trailing slashes, and remove "index" from URLs. The .htaccess looked something like this:
# Remove ".html" using htaccess
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.html\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301,L]

# Internally add .html if necessary
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.html [L]

# Remove "index" from directory index pages
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# Remove trailing "/" if not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect index
RedirectPermanent /index /

I moved the page to a new folder and updated the redirect:
RedirectPermanent /oldpage /newfolder/newpage.html

I set a canonical tag pointing to the old URL on the new page and requested indexing in Google Search Console (GSC). After some time, both the old and new URLs started appearing in the SERPs, with significant ranking improvements.
Interestingly, both old URLs (with and without ".html") now redirect to the new URL, which had a canonical pointing back to the old URL. The SERPs display my new snippet for the old URL and the old snippet for the ".html" version.
I've removed the canonical tag but still don't fully understand what happened. Could someone explain why both URLs are now indexed, why rankings improved, and the overall process?
Best regards,
Chris
PS. Not sure, if im allowed to post live URLs, so im posting example.com URLs.
